# Is there a Linux tool for extracting embedded resources from EXEs?

Tags: linux, open-source, .net, python

Does anyone know of a Linux tool for extracting embedded resources (images, EXEs, DLLs, etc) from EXEs, especially for .NET and VC++ EXEs?